# Best way to iterate over multiple arrays of different types

Tags: go

I just started learning Go and I come from a background of OOP.

So for example, say I have three structs like so:

```
type Parent struct {

}

type Foo struct {
    *Parent
}

type Bar struct {
    *Parent
}
```

The Foo and Bar structs both extend Parent. If I have an array of `Foo`'s, and an array of `Bar`'s, is there a way to merge these into a single array/slice of `Parent`s?

If not, then what is the best way to iterate over the two arrays at once if I know I will only be accessing properties inherited from `Parent`?

Comment: There is no inheritance in Go, so it isn't possible to have "Foo and Bar structs both extend Parent". Can you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: @Adrian Well yeah I know it's not inheritance but I don't know what else to call it. When I use the syntax provided though it seems to behave like inheritance. i.e. the properties of `Parent` are accessible from `Foo`.

Comment: It's called embedding, and it's important not to confuse it with inheritance, particularly because it does not allow for the kind of behavior you're describing.

Comment: @chrispytoes: that's composition, which is orthogonal to inheritance. The selector in Go give you some automatic delegation, which allows you to satisfy particular methods sets, but that never creates an "Is A" relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go does not support inheritance, and the only polymorphism it supports is interfaces. What you've got in the example code is called embedding, and it does not offer polymorphism; if you embed `Parent` in `Foo`, that does not let you assign a `Foo`-type value to a `Parent`-type variable or slice.

The closest you can get to what you describe would be using interfaces. If `Parent` implements some interface (let's say `Baz`), then embedding `Parent` in `Foo` and `Bar` means that both will also implement that same interface. This in turn means that you can have a slice of the interface type `[]Baz` into which you could put values of type `Parent`, `Foo`, or `Bar`. Note that interfaces can only specify methods, not fields, so when using values of the interface type, you'll only be able to access the methods of the interface, not any fields that might be specified in `Parent`, `Foo`, or `Bar`.